# Fixing DataGrid Header Sort on user-defined header using a StackPanel

Tags: wpf, datagridcolumnheader

I have a DataGrid, filled from an ObservableCollection.

```
                <Style x:Key="DGHdr_2LineNormal" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Height"                       Value="40" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"                       Value="0,2,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"            Value="Bottom" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"     Value="Bottom" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"          Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"   Value="Center" />
            </Style>

            ...........................

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  GridLinesVisibility="None"
                  Name="MatipBatapConfigList"               
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DGHdr_2LineNormal}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            ...........................
        </DataGrid>
```

Several of the ColumnHeaderStyle items are "normal" (1 line of text):

```
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.hdrSystemName}"
                        Header="Name">
```

but for some, I use a StackPanel so I can have multiple lines, using TextBox items,
varying the font size between them:

```
            <Style x:Key="DGHdr_2LineStackPanel" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Width"                        Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Height"                       Value="40" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"                       Value="0,0,0,-2" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"          Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"   Value="Center" />
            </Style>

            ...........................

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.DestAddr}"
                        HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DGHdr_2LineStackPanel}" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,-2">
                            <TextBox Text="Destination" IsReadOnly="True"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="9"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Padding="0" Height="16" Background="Transparent"/>
                            <TextBox Text="Address"  IsReadOnly="True"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Padding="0" Height="18" Background="Transparent"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

The problem I have is on sorting each column.  In the "normal" case, I can click anywhere on the column header to sort it.  In the StackPanel case, though, there is only a thin, 4-pixel high area at the top (the height of the sort arrow) in which you can sort the column.

Is there a way to change the StackPanel cases such that it acts like the "normal" case, in that you can click anywhere in the header to sort it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, mm8. Worked perfectly! Hadn't seen the attribute IsHitTestVisible  before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `TextBox` elements with `TextBlock` elements in the header, or set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the `TextBox` elements to `false`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,-2">
    <TextBox Text="Destination" IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="9"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Padding="0" Height="16" Background="Transparent"/>
    <TextBox Text="Address"  IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Padding="0" Height="18" Background="Transparent"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: IsHitTestVisible="False" fixed the sorting, but now ToolTip no longer works for column header!  I've tried both putting the ToolTip on each of the TextBoxe'es, and adding a <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle> ... <ToolTip...>, neither work